# Ruby: Reverse method from scratch

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a coding challenge practice problem that is asking me to put together a method that reverses a string and have come up with:

```
def reverse(string)
   idx = 1
   array_s = []
    while idx <= string.length
        array_s.push(string[string.length - idx])
        idx = idx + 1
    end    
    new_string = array_s.join("")
    puts new_string
end
```

When I run the test given at the end,

```
puts(
  'reverse("abc") == "cba": ' + (reverse("abc") == "cba").to_s
)
puts(
  'reverse("a") == "a": ' + (reverse("a") == "a").to_s
)
puts(
  'reverse("") == "": ' + (reverse("") == "").to_s
)
```

it seems to show that the strings reverse, but it still prints false. Is there anything I'm missing in the method I wrote? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your function is working as expected, it is the last line that is causing you issues.

```
puts new_string
```

`puts` returns `nil`, ruby uses implicit returns unless you explicitly say `return`, so it returns the result from the last line of code, in this case is `nil`.

If you just do `new_string` or `return new_string`, it will work.

Or if you want to print it to the screen and return it as the result, you can do

```
p new_string
```

Comment: `p new_string` will return the argument, which is the string, but it does a little bit more than also print to the screen.  It uses `inspect` and so it will also show the quotes around it.  `p` is not a shortcut for `puts`.

Answer (score 0):

davidhu2000 has answered your question correctly but i would suggest refactoring the code:

```
f = "forward"

puts f.reverse 

# drawrof
```

of if you really want:

```
def reverse(string)
   return string.reverse
end
```